# How to change syntax of column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have df1:

```
ID   Time
1    16:00:00
2    14:30:00
3    9:23:00
4    10:00:00
5    23:59:00
```

and would like to change the current 'character' column 'Time' into a an 'integer' as below:

```
ID   Time
1    1600
2    1430
3    923
4    1000
5    2359
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could replace the `:`'s, make numeric, divide by 100, and convert to integer like this:

```
df1$Time = as.integer(as.numeric(gsub(':', '', df1$Time))/100)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `as.POSIXct()`.

> Functions to manipulate objects of classes "POSIXlt" and "POSIXct" representing calendar dates and times.

[R Documents as.POSIXct()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/as.POSIX*)

So in the case of row 1: `as.POSIXct("16:00:00", format = "%H%M")`

Then use `as.numeric` if you need it to truly be an int.

> Converts a character matrix to a numeric matrix.

[R Docs as.Numeric()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/haplotypes/versions/1.1.2/topics/as.numeric-methods)

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 <- data.frame(Time = "16:00:00")
df1[, "Time"] <- as.numeric(paste0(substr(df1[, "Time"], 1, 2), substr(df1[, "Time"], 4, 5)))
print(df1)
#   Time
# 1 1600
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to process this, but here's one example:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- mutate(df1, Time = gsub(":", "", Time) # replace colons with blanks
df1 <- mutate(df1, Time = as.numeric(Time)/100) # coerce to numeric type, divide by 100
```